# CSS @import issue

Tags: css, media-queries, css-import

I was trying to add my other CSS file to my project's main CSS file, but `@import` is not working for the second one. what should I  do?

[image: Screenshot of the problem of using @import]

I was hoping to upload multiple CSS files import them to the main one and link the main css file with my html file.

Comment: Looks more like a cascade issue than an import one. But you need to post the actual code in your question, not images of code.

Comment: @Willow: I think you messed things up. `@import` is supported by all major browsers while `@import: supports() as import` is probably what you meant. A more detailed table can be found here: https://caniuse.com/?search=%40import

Comment: @Ferris yes! I messed this up :) deleting my original comment so as not to confuse folks

Answer (score 0):

Hello Siyam Zaman Shishir,

Great effort on your part! Just a couple of tweaks for optimization:

The @import statements should directly reference your files:

```
@import url(./library.css);
@import url(./screen.css);
```

You've set the background-color in both the style.css and screen.css, causing a conflict due to CSS hierarchies. To resolve this, simply add !important within the @media statement in screen.css:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background-color: red !important;
  }
}
```

I made a test just like your project. Let me share what I did here:

1. The files:
   C:\Project\test
   C:\Project\test\index.html
   C:\Project\test\css
   C:\Project\test\css\library.css
   C:\Project\test\css\screen.css
   C:\Project\test\css\style.css
2. HTML:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="UTF-8">
           <meta name="viewport"
               content="width=device-width,
               initial-scale=1">
           <link rel="stylesheet"
               href="./css/style.css">
           <title>log in</title>
       </head>
       <body>

       </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. style.css

   ```
   @import url(./library.css);
   @import url(./screen.css);

   body{
       background-color:
           var(--color-bg);
   }
   ```
4. library.css

   ```
   :root{
       --color-bg: #CCC;
   }
   ```
5. screen.css

   ```
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
     body{
        background-color: red !important;
     }
   }
   ```

It is working as expected!
[screen test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n351.gif)
If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Best regards,
Fabio.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did not notice that. but my main problem was I couldn't use that @import feature to import my CSS properties from another file into my main CSS file. can you help me?

Comment: Sure! What property are you trying to use? let's try to do a test together! :)